# Stopping Page Refresh while including a jsp using jsp:include

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, struts2

I have a JSP which is like:

```
<s:form action="taction" form="tform">
<table>
<tr>
<td onclick="callBut1()">Call Jsp1</td>
<td><s:if test="#session.bvalue=='true'"><jsp:include page="/A.jsp"/></s:if></td>
</tr>
</table>
<s:hidden name="buttonvalue"/>
</s:form>
```

JS file is:

```
function callBut1(){
    document.tform.buttonvalue.value="selected";
    document.tform.submit();  
}
```

Now when I click the td (i.e Call Jsp1) the page refreshes as I'm using `document.form.submit()` in the script.

Is there any way that I can do this without page refresh ?

Comment: Try AJAX [JSPAndAJAXExamples](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/JSPAndAJAXExamples)

Comment: `jsp:include` is evaluated server side before the page is rendered, and has nothing to do with your question, that basically can be answered with: use AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `submit`, your page refresh.

if you want do this without refreshing the page, use [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

like this:

```
function callBut1(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'taction',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html"
    }).done(function(data){
          //do what you want
    });
}
```